# Iteration count in Scipy's Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I'm trying to get a number of iterations needed until convergence for finding the `k` smallest eigenvalues of a matrix. While scipy can find the eigenvalues without much difficulty, there's no way that I see to easily get out the number of iterations needed.

In the code block as shown, my thought was that the addition of the counter in variable *i* would solve my problem, but this can't be the case as *i* can be greater than maxiter, a clear contradiction.

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg._eigen.arpack as bark
#%%
def ct(v):    
    return np.conj(v.T)

def eigsb(A, k=6, M=None, sigma=None, which='LM', v0=None,
         ncv=None, maxiter=None, tol=0, return_eigenvectors=True,
         Minv=None, OPinv=None, OPpart=None):
        n = A.shape[0]
        mode = 1
        M_matvec = None
        Minv_matvec = None
        matvec = bark._aslinearoperator_with_dtype(A).matvec
        params = bark._UnsymmetricArpackParams(n, k, A.dtype.char, matvec, mode,
                                      M_matvec, Minv_matvec, sigma,
                                      ncv, v0, maxiter, which, tol)

        i=0
        while not params.converged:
            params.iterate()
            i=i+1
        return i,params.extract(return_eigenvectors)

###Make Herimtian Matrix
d = 50
mat = np.random.rand(d,d)+ 1j * (np.random.rand(d,d))
mat = mat - (np.random.rand(d,d)+ 1j * (np.random.rand(d,d)))
mat = mat + ct(mat)
###
i,(vals, vecs) = eigsb(mat, k=1, which='SR', ncv=6, maxiter=50)
```

Is there a different way I should be going about this? Or is there some conversion between the count *i* and the true iteration value I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that tol is playing a role here. I tried setting non-zero positive value for tol and it iterates exactly same number of times regardless of value of d or maxiter. Try setting tol as non-zero positive and check.

Reference :
https://sisl.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.2/_modules/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.html

```
class IterInv(LinearOperator):
    """
    IterInv:
       helper class to repeatedly solve M*x=b
       using an iterative method.
    """
    def __init__(self, M, ifunc=gmres, tol=0):
        if tol <= 0:
            # when tol=0, ARPACK uses machine tolerance as calculated
            # by LAPACK's _LAMCH function.  We should match this
            tol = 2 * np.finfo(M.dtype).eps

tol : float, optional
        Relative accuracy for eigenvalues (stopping criterion)
        The default value of 0 implies machine precision.
```

Comment: Could you show your example of this? For different tolerances I'm getting different different iteration counts for different d or maxiter. Not only that, even for the same matrix, if I run the operation sometimes I can get different iteration counts out of it.

Comment: I used your code as example. @AProjans.